# MATLAB: How to test each element of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Say I had a row vector: `A= [1,4,5.6]`

and I wanted to have the following

```
if floor(A)~=A
error('vector contains non-integers')
else
*rest of program*
end
```

How would I need my code to be such that I can display the error message (and hence stop the program) if at least one of the elements in the row vector meets the `if` conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ***ANY*** of them trigger the condition?

`if any(floor(A)~=A)`

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes and no. Any integer (to a certain value) can be represented perfectly, so I guess it depends on where the values come from. If they come from a text file, there is no problem with this code, if they come from a numerical method, then there may be problems.

Comment: anyway I prefer `if any (abs(A - floor(A)) > eps)`

Comment: @rahnema1 I work with numerical algorithms, I agree with that. But there are cases where you are interested in having an integer `A`, not an `A` that is close to another number.

Comment: @rahnema1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917167/find-a-number-before-another-specific-number-on-a-vector/40917241?noredirect=1#comment69046811_40917241

Comment: @AnderBiguri So we are agree but since  result of floor(A) is a double not an integer the comparison may become problematic

Comment: @rahnema1 no, comparison between integer numbers (in float representation) is not a problem. Try `(0.1+0.2)==0.3` and `(1+2)==3` Change the numbers as pleased. Integers can be accurately represented in float and double to a very big number

Comment: @beaker I and you and Ander Biguri are agree although that question  is slightly different. I learn  from your Instructive comments